# How do you link to a specific part of the page in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

To make a typical "Go back to top" link usually you would put, say

```
<a id="top"></a>
[...]
<a href="#top">Top</a>
```

In AngularJS this link tries to go to example.com/#top instead, therefore it goes back to the default route. How do you tell angular treat this link appropriately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the $anchorScroll service.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$anchorScroll](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24anchorScroll)