# <a href="#"> not working after adding angularjs on the project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My project has some primitive code  .asp file which uses   After adding angularjs to the code base these pop-ups have stopped opening. it now appending the # at the end of url after clicking on the link.

```
 <td><span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_ysush783jsks popover=true popoverContent=link"><a href="#"><img src="/images/help.png"/></a></span></td>
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127714/how-do-you-link-to-a-specific-part-of-the-page-in-angular

Comment: Angular uses # hashtags for routing.  If you just want to use angular for making forms, then don't add the angular-router script, just use angular.min.js and nothing else.  Optionally, don't use Anchor tags that link to nothing, whats the point?

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap popover, [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907376/twitter-bootstrap-popover-doesnt-work-with-angularjs) might be the same case.